# Applying advanced parameter settings with RQGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-grass-plugin, rqgis

I am working on stream network delineation with GRASS 7 in RQGIS, the 'r.stream.extract' algorithm in particular. However, the algorithm returns erroneous result when the Advanced parameter, "v.out.ogr output type" has not been defined as "line". The advanced parameters setting is accessible in the QGIS GUI ver 2.14.17 (as shown below)

[image]

but couldn't be found as argument in RQGIS.

[image]

I wonder if there is anything that I have missed. Is there any workaround to solve this?

Comment: Try setting `GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER` as 2. The options from the GUI are seen as index values: `auto` = 0; `point` = 1; `line` = 2; and `area` = 3.

Comment: Nice one! Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joseph has already told you the correct answer. But just to make it clear. To find out about possible values for a specific parameter, run `get_usage()`. In your case run:

```
get_usage("grass7:r.stream.extract")
```

This results in:

```
ALGORITHM: r.stream.extract - Stream network extraction
elevation <ParameterRaster>
  accumulation <ParameterRaster>
  depression <ParameterRaster>
  threshold <ParameterNumber>
  mexp <ParameterNumber>
  stream_length <ParameterNumber>
  d8cut <ParameterNumber>
  GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
  GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
  GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER <ParameterSelection>
  stream_raster <OutputRaster>
  stream_vector <OutputVector>
  direction <OutputRaster>


GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER(v.out.ogr output type)
0 - auto
1 - point
2 - line
3 - area
```

So setting `GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER` to `2` (`"line"` should also work), as pointed out by Joseph, should do what you want.